# Bash completion: filter out backup (~) files

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, autocomplete

I would like bash to filter out backup files, with a name ending in ~ (tilde), when auto-completing filenames.

I have written a script to set this when using vim (I have very little experience with shell scripting):

```
#!/bin/bash

no_backups_complete()
{
    local cur=$2

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -o plusdirs -f -X '*\~' -- "$cur" ) )

    return 0
}

complete -o filenames -F no_backups_complete vim
```

However, running the script has no apparent effect, vim[Tab] still shows every file.

I have tried escaping / not escaping the ~, and putting $2 and $cur in / not in quotes, with no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax works perfectly, so most likely it's not getting added to your bash environment for one reason or another.

#### See if it is loaded in your environment:

Open a new bash terminal window and run:

```
declare -F | grep no_backups_complete
```

To see the function declaration (if it is available):

```
type no_backups_complete
```

If you get a result, for the first commmand, like:

```
declare -f no_backups_complete
```

that indicates that it is loaded in the environment; if there is no result it is not. The type response should be '... not found' if it isn't available, or list the function definition if it is available.

Continuing with the assumption that it is *not* loaded in your bash environment:

#### Where did you put the file?

- The customary location is in the directory /etc/bash_completion.d/. It does not need to be marked executable to be put in that directory, or have any particular name. You have the format correct.
- As a test, simply type `source /path/to/your/completion.file` and then see if vim 'ignores' files ending in tildes. It should - it did in my bash shell.
- Make sure you:
   1. copy contents out of the script and into your .bashrc file, *or* 
  2. copy it to /etc/bash_completion.d/ *or* 
  3. have the completion file sourced by .bashrc

Whatever method you go with, if you don't source the file, you'll need to restart the terminal for it to kick in. If it is in the /etc/bash_completion.d directory reloading bash did not load it; I had to close the terminal window and reopen it - that might be terminal program specific, but sourcing .bashrc wasn't enough for that one case (option 2). The other two options would start working once .bashrc is sourced.

If *it is* loaded in your environment; i.e. the `declare -F | grep ..`  and `type ..` commands return expected values, post back with the results. I think that is far less likely, and it's worth running through these quick checks before going down that route.